# Limit UICollectionView height using inequality constraints and priorities

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a collection view pinned to its superview bottom, left, and right edges and a text field pinned to superview top, left, and right. The collection view's height is increased in `updateConstraints` from the bottom up with a height constraint based on its content size as more items are added to it.

I'd like the collection view height to grow but not exceed the
bottom of the textField above it with an inequality constraint on the
collection view's top edge. Here's what I've tried:

```
self.topResistanceConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
    toItem:self.textField
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:0];
[self addConstraint:self.topResistanceConstraint];

CGSize size = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;

self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:nil
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:size.height];
[self addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
```

This results in unsatisfiable constraints, and recovers (and actually appears to work), but it's not a good solution and doesn't work if the layout needs to adapt to a keyboard appearing or disappearing. Any suggestions how to create constraints or priorities to get this to work without breaking constraints?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, simply setting the heightConstraint to low priority works well. The topResistanceConstraint's priority is required, and prevents the collection view's top from exceeding the bottom of the text field.

```
self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:nil
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:size.height];

// set a low priority on height
self.heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityLow;

[self addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution for this problem is to create a height and top constraint
(top constrains related by "NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual") for the collectionView in the storyboard and create the outlet for both.
After that get the collectionView item count and than dynamically calculate the height of the collectionView as below

```
NSInteger count = 5;
CGFloat collectionViewHeight = count/2 * cellHeight; // for collectionView with two(2) columns
CGFloat maxCollectionViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.textField.frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(self.textField.frame);
if (collectionViewHeight < maxCollectionViewHeight ) {
    self.heightConstraint.constant = collectionViewHeight;
} else {
    self.topConstraint.constant = 20; // Min spacing between two views;
}
```

Comment: size is already calculated with self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize. What I'd like to accomplish is to eliminate ambiguous layout while making the top constraint have higher priority over height constraint.